# Is a 16-day Apple Beta Review time normal?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, beta

I've submitted an iOS beta Testflight build for external testing on Jan 9th and it went into review that same day and has not changed status since. Normally it's only a few days as our previous beta took 2 days and it was a few days before. However, it's been over 2 weeks and counting so far.

I submitted an expedited beta review on the 21st (3 days ago) out of desperation to get our latest beta to our customers to test and it's like our app has been put into a void and forgotten about.

There is no way to contact our review team, so I'm not sure what's going on or if its some kind of fall back from the "holiday rush". Has anyone else been experiencing these long app beta review times? AppReviewTimes.com is reporting an impressive 2 days for full app reviews.

Comment: 16 days is excessive, in my opinion.  What do you mean by "there's no way to contact our review team"?  As part of your Apple Developer agreement you get 2 free support requests.  Did you try that?

Comment: I can only request a get code-level assistance (via the Code-level support in the dev dashboard) and an expedited app review (via the contact us prompt in iTunesConnect). I have done the latter and assumed that the code-level support technical question would help with more advanced areas rather than "our beta app is still in review" items. I did go through the prompts again at your comment and got an item to create a general support ticket and have filed a ticket in there. Would you suggest that I use a code level support request on this? If it's relevant for them I can

Comment: @fsb sorry forgot to mention you in my above comment. It wouldn't let me edit the message

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing it to a code-level request.  I see Apple developer support on the Developer Forum quite often.  Maybe you can ask about this over there and see if an Apple person can assist?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a normal review time.

## Review Times

You can get a gauge of average App Store review times on http://appreviewtimes.com

> This site tracks the average App Store review times for both the iOS and the Mac App Store using data crowdsourced from iOS and Mac developers.

The current average iOS review time is **2 days**.

Having submitted an expedited beta review, there is nothing you can officially do but wait. As a developer, the review process can feel capricious.

Comment: the OP already mentioned that in the question with that link

Comment: They wanted to know if the time was normal, it is not. They wanted to know what options they have, none. This answer supports their intuition. That can be helpful and reassuring to those asking questions. The comments are also helpful but answers are needed to fit this Ask Different's approach.

Comment: Alas, http://appreviewtimes.com has shutdown, with a nice explanation why.   Of course, I'm here looking because I've seen the review time go from "about a day" to "about a week".